# unit test case for a function which doesn't returns but calls other function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on a project using angularjs(1.x) as framework. In this project, I have a web interface and I make some backend request. I felt the need to write testing for this tool. So, I started writing unit test cases for this. But now, I am not able to figure out to write test case for some of the functions. My problem is:

I am trying to write test case of the function which is making backend request, and on either `success` or `error`, I am calling other function. So, basically, this function is not returning anything. So, How I can test this function?

Code snippet is:

```
public makePutRequest(): void {
    this.backendService.putBackendRequest(url, backendData, config)
    .then((success) => {
        successFunction(success); // function call on success
    }, (error) => {
        errorFunction(error);   // function call on error
    })
}
```

function in backendService is:

```
public putBackendRequest(url, backendData, config){
    let defered = this.$q.defer();
    this.$httpService.put(url, backendData, config)
        .success((data, status, headers, config): void => {
            if (status === 200) {
                // do some further manipulation with data.
            }
            return defered.resolve(data);
        })
        .error((data, status, headers, config): void => {
            if (status === 500) {
                // do some other manipulation.
            }
            return defered.reject(data);
        });
    return defered.promise;
}
```

I am writing unit test test cases using karma as test runner and jasmine as testing framework with angularjs(1.x) as framework.

Now, I am not able to figure out how to write test case for the function `makePutRequest` because it is getting `promise`, and on `resolve` of promise it is calling one function and on `reject` it is calling other function.

I am new to write unit testing in angularjs. Any useful suggestion will be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: Did you try mocking your makePutRequest call

Comment: @ukn: I am writing test case for makePutRequest function. Why should I mock that function?

Comment: My bad, i was thinking about mocking putBackendRequest but i wrote makePutRequest.

Comment: @ukn: Can you elaborate, how mocking *putBackendRequest* function will help me?

Comment: You will be able to test what matters. Here you want to test what happens when you get a success or an error. It doesn't matter what happens elsewhere. Since your function does not return anything, you should test what are the side effects.

Comment: @ukn: Can you be specific in your comment? I am not able to get what exactly u want to say

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a test double for backendService.  The test double will simply reject or resolve as you dictate.  You did not mention what unit testing framework you are using, but you can manually build a test double, or use a mocking framework from your unit test to make a test double that responds the way you want.  Some test libraries, like Jasmine, come with the ability to create test doubles built in.

Here is an example of a manually built test double for the same type of service (a service that calls a backend).  You need some kind of mechanism to inject the test double into the code under test that calls the service.  In example below I am using constructor dependency injection.

The class being tested is "App".  The dependency / service that App calls is referred to as "Api".  In the example below, I am testing that after App succesfully receives data from a resolved promise returned by the service, it updates state on App appropriately.

```
  it('loads drugs when attached to dom', function(done) {

    let response = new Response(JSON.stringify(
      [{drugId : "1", name: "drug1", classifications : []}]
    ));

    let fetchPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
      resolve(response.json());
    });

    let mockApi = { getDrugs : function() {
      return fetchPromise;
    }};

    let app = new App(mockApi);

    app.attached();

    fetchPromise.then( function() {
      expect(app.availableDrugs.length).toBe(1);
      expect(app.availableDrugs[0].drugId).toBe("1");
      expect(app.availableDrugs[0].name).toBe("drug1");
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Its always good to read the question carefully. I specifically mentioned that I am using **jasmine** as testing framework. Also, I am writing test case for *makePutRequest* function, but not the *putBackendRequest* function of backendService